# Why Vlad's dialogue always has the word "Luck" between quotes?

Tags: magicka

So Magicka is a game with a lot of subtle (and not so subtle) references to popular culture. But one thing has bothered me back when I played and I failed to figure it out - Vlad would often finish his dialogue by saying *Good "Luck"!* with the word *Luck* always shown under quotes.

[image: Good "Luck" example]

What is the reason for this? Is this some reference I can't figure out or just a random joke of some kind?

Edit: some **possible spoilers** for the first game story in the comments of this post.

Comment: Maybe because he want you death? I mean he want you death

Comment: @Serverfrog means: "It can be because he wants you to die"

Comment: Why would that be? Disregarding the fact he's a vampire, I never got the impression he's the "bad guy" in any way (his later actions seem to be simply because of his bad judgement, rather than ill intentions).

Comment: Possibly to attempt sarcasm.  Written sarcasm is pretty difficult.

Comment: That's possible, but I don't understand why he would be sarcastic about it (again, I don't see him as a "bad guy" in the game, especially since he seems vital to the plot resolution and stopping Assataur).

Comment: It could be that he just doesn't believe in luck

Comment: Could be a fourth-wall breaking reference to the largely deterministic nature of video games (there is no such thing as "luck")